# Uncaught TypeError: Element.prototype is undefined BS 5.2.3 - BS 5.2 Navbar Multi Level and Mega Menu

Tags: select, menu, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I have made an implementation of the Menu
`[https://codepen.io/typo3-freelancer/pen/poEvyGj](https://codepen.io/typo3-freelancer/pen/poEvyGj)` and everything goes well, until I get to a form, where some dynamic "selects" are generated (Country, Departament & City. The form works perfectly, but the menu stops working when I select the list of departments, I start getting the following errors:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Element.prototype is undefined
    find selector-engine.js:16
    clearMenus dropdown.js:360
    i event-handler.js:98
    D event-handler.js:184
    on event-handler.js:217
    <anonymous> dropdown.js:441
    <anonymous> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
    <anonymous> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
selector-engine.js:16:11

Uncaught TypeError: Element.prototype is undefined
    find selector-engine.js:16
    clearMenus dropdown.js:360
    i event-handler.js:98
selector-engine.js:16:11

Uncaught TypeError: Element.prototype is undefined
    find selector-engine.js:16
    clearMenus dropdown.js:360
    i event-handler.js:98
selector-engine.js:16:11

Uncaught TypeError: Element.prototype is undefined
    find selector-engine.js:16
    clearMenus dropdown.js:360
    i event-handler.js:98
    D event-handler.js:184
    on event-handler.js:217
    <anonymous> dropdown.js:441
    <anonymous> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
    <anonymous> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
selector-engine.js:16:11`
```

and the same errors are repeated when I try to drop down the menu or when I select the dropdown list (select).

Can anyone give me an idea of ​​what could be going on? It only happens to me with dynamic selects. With the static select I have no problem and the menu works perfectly.

Thank you very much in advance.

I don't know if it has to do with the way objects are created, if I'm missing some class or something. I hope you can guide me, thank you